# What actually happens when a recursive function is also a generator?

Tags: python, recursion, generator

I am writing a function that, given an array, returns a list of possible permutations.
I came up with the following and it works great:

```
def _permutate(elems):
    if len(elems) <= 1:
        yield elems
    else:
        for i in range(len(elems)):
            for perm in _permutate(elems[:i] + elems[i+1:]):
                yield [elems[i]] + perm
```

So running `print(list(_permutate([2, 1, 3])))` gives me: `[[2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [3, 2, 1], [3, 1, 2]]`

But I want to know what's actually happening in the background...
I know a recursive function adds to a stack until it reaches it's base case and then works backwards down the stack to give you a result, and then a generator function pauses computation at it's first yield and returns a generator that you have to loop through to get the results of each yield, but I'm really confused as to what happens when you put the two together.

---

Rewriting the function with debug statements

```
def _permutate(elems):
    if len(elems) <= 1:
        print(elems) # NEW
        yield elems
    else:
        for i in range(len(elems)):
            for perm in _permutate(elems[:i] + elems[i+1:]):
                print("NEW", [elems[i]], perm)  # NEW
                yield [elems[i]] + perm
```

And then running

```
gen = _permutate([1,2,3,4,5])
print('NEXT', next(gen))
print('NEXT', next(gen))    
print('NEXT', next(gen))
print('NEXT', next(gen))
print('NEXT', next(gen))
print('NEXT', next(gen))
print('NEXT', next(gen))
```

Shows a bit clearer what's going on:

```
[5]
NEW [4] [5]
NEW [3] [4, 5]
NEW [2] [3, 4, 5]
NEW [1] [2, 3, 4, 5]
NEXT [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[4]
NEW [5] [4]
NEW [3] [5, 4]
NEW [2] [3, 5, 4]
NEW [1] [2, 3, 5, 4]
NEXT [1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
[5]
NEW [3] [5]
NEW [4] [3, 5]
NEW [2] [4, 3, 5]
NEW [1] [2, 4, 3, 5]
NEXT [1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
[3]
NEW [5] [3]
NEW [4] [5, 3]
NEW [2] [4, 5, 3]
NEW [1] [2, 4, 5, 3]
NEXT [1, 2, 4, 5, 3]
[4]
NEW [3] [4]
NEW [5] [3, 4]
NEW [2] [5, 3, 4]
NEW [1] [2, 5, 3, 4]
NEXT [1, 2, 5, 3, 4]
[3]
NEW [4] [3]
NEW [5] [4, 3]
NEW [2] [5, 4, 3]
NEW [1] [2, 5, 4, 3]
NEXT [1, 2, 5, 4, 3]
[5]
NEW [4] [5]
NEW [2] [4, 5]
NEW [3] [2, 4, 5]
NEW [1] [3, 2, 4, 5]
NEXT [1, 3, 2, 4, 5]
```

---

Found an article [here](https://prosperocoder.com/posts/python/recursive-generators-in-python/) that shows a table of what happens during the recursive generator.
I've tried recreating this table with an array [1,2,3]
[image]

Comment: The important thing to understatnd: recursion is no different than calling another function. Suppose you defined a function, `_permutate_2`, and it had the exact same code as `_permute` and called *that* inside `_permute`... it works like that

Comment: So it's very simple, `_permutate(elems[:i] + elems[i+1:])` creates *a new generator object*, which is iterated over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did an experiment to illustrate how the flow of the generator works:

```
def _permutate(elems):
    if len(elems) <= 1:
        print(elems) # NEW
        yield elems
    else:
        for i in range(len(elems)):
            for perm in _permutate(elems[:i] + elems[i+1:]):
                print([elems[i]] + perm)  # NEW
                yield [elems[i]] + perm

# NEW
gen = _permutate([1,2,3,4,5])
print('NEXT', next(gen))
print('NEXT', next(gen))
print('NEXT', next(gen))
print('NEXT', next(gen))
print('NEXT', next(gen))
print('NEXT', next(gen))
print('NEXT', next(gen))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[5]
[4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
NEXT [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[4]
[5, 4]
[3, 5, 4]
[2, 3, 5, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
NEXT [1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
[5]
[3, 5]
[4, 3, 5]
[2, 4, 3, 5]
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
NEXT [1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
[3]
[5, 3]
[4, 5, 3]
[2, 4, 5, 3]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 3]
NEXT [1, 2, 4, 5, 3]
[4]
[3, 4]
[5, 3, 4]
[2, 5, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 5, 3, 4]
NEXT [1, 2, 5, 3, 4]
[3]
[4, 3]
[5, 4, 3]
[2, 5, 4, 3]
[1, 2, 5, 4, 3]
NEXT [1, 2, 5, 4, 3]
[5]
[4, 5]
[2, 4, 5]
[3, 2, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 2, 4, 5]
NEXT [1, 3, 2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes it a bit clearer.
So the first yield that is encountered is in the basecase of the recusive part of the function? 
So it should technically pause there but we have a for loop iterating over the generator that's returned and that's why we see the arrays before the "NEXT" print statements?

Comment: @Domanowska To be honest I had started writing an explanation of what was happening but then got a little bit lost myself. What I think is that the only recursive call is in "for perm in _permutate(...)", and I believe that that fully consumes that recursion of the generator until it has no more yields, at which point we go back up in scope.

Comment: @Domanowska I think it starts to make sense if you follow the logic of it with pen and paper starting with [1, 2] as an input, then once you are satisfied with that, try with [0, 1, 2] instead.

Comment: Ah I see, I've replaced your `print([elems[i]] + perm)` with `print("NEW", [elems[i]], perm)` and I think it shows exactly that.